# How to create signed URL to fetch private content from cloud front in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I am developing Android app in Kotlin. We need to fetch audio from amazon cloud front. How to create signed URL for amazon cloud front to access private content in Android? Is there any library to create signed URL for amazon cloud front?

Need to play an audio file without downloading and need to download the audio file for different purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem today, so thought I'd post the solution here if anyone runs into the same issue.

I just followed the [link](https://github.com/leedoing/cloudfront-signed-url-cookie/blob/master/signed-url.java). Now I am able to create the signed url in cloud-front.